# Bitvise SSH Server - Connection works first time, than never seen again

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, bitvise

I have a ssh server set up with bitvise. My internet provider is Comcast and recently they had to change the lines so the internet was down. This server has been working for 2-3 years flawlessly. **Now my issue is that the first time I connect to the server I am successful but any other attempts are not.**

Bitvise does not see the 2nd attempted connection so I am trying to figure out what is going on. If my windows firewall is blocking it, is there somewhere I can see that? Is comcast known to allow one connection than block it forever afterwards? Any tips on where to get started? Comcast support is non existent so I am not sure what to do.

- Connection works first time only, than the IP seems to get blocked
- Port 48300 and set up to forward to the server
- Windows 7
- Bitvise SSH Server

Answer (score 0):

Figured out Comcast was blocking it from their site not the router. On the Comcast/xfinity site they have a security warning. Clicking through the warning you finally get to a page that shows the blocked connections with details. You can get to a page with the option to unblock the accounts for a maximum of 30 days at a time. The link for me was here: https://internet.xfinity.com/network/security/device/someLongNumberHere/threat-history/REMOTE_ACCESS